# Windows server 2003 R2 supported guest operating system

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, windows, windows-server-2003-r2

In this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc794868%28WS.10%29.aspx) it is mentioned like window server 2012 can be used as guest OS in window server 2008 R2

Can I run windows 8 or window 7 as guest OS in window server 2003 R2 as virtual machine? Even though window server 2003 r2 is old does it support it?

I have purchased Windows server 2012 separately (With new hardware parts). But I want to utilise existing server 2003 R2 license and its CALs (In my existing old server hardware). I have another desktop PC with TFS 2012 running on windows 8. But TFS 2012 cannot be installed to win server 2003 r2. So i have planned to install win server 2003 in one of my server and then create a virtual windows 8 in that. So i can install TFS for that virtual PC. Whether my plan is workable?
Although i cannot install TFS on my main server which has windows server 2012 because of performance issue and accessibility for my employees.

Comment: A guest VM using what virtualization tech?  Virtualbox?  VMWare Workstation?  Bob's Virtual Express Millennial Edition?  What have you tried or what issues are you running into setting it up?

Comment: After your edit...again I don't get the true gist of your question.  Were you hoping for a "Sure...you can do that...go forth and conquer!" answer?  I'm assuming you didn't know the experts here would come down on you for wanting to do this...but why didn't you simply try it in a test environment and see if it worked for you.  Forget best practices, etc.  You don't seem to care about those regardless, so why not just test and see if running TFS 2012 on a Win8 VM on VBOX on a 2003 R2 server in production works for you?

Comment: If someone hasn't mentioned it yet [Hyper-V Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/dn205299.aspx) (a separate product from the Hyper-V Role in Server 2008 and newer) is a FREE virtualization Operating System from Microsoft. All the virtualization goodness of Hyper-V, no cost.

Answer (score 5):

The post you've linked to is for Hyper-V. Server 2003 doesn't have Hyper-V. That launched with 2008. So, no, you can't virtualize anything with the *native* Windows virtualization platform. You can install some type 2 hypervisor, like VirtualBox, but that's bad for a production environment.

Server 2003 R2 only has about a year of support left at this point. Upgrade.

Comment: This virtual pc will be used for production purpose. (TFS 2012 will be installed in this pc)

Comment: For the love of $deity, don't use VB in production. Can't you install 2012 on the server over 2003 and then use Hyper-V in 2012?

Comment: @ITresearcher maybe you should hire someone with experience to give you some help?